# Entire function and the series of its successive derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

I recently came across the result that if $g$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of a point $z_0$ and 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{g^{(n)}(z_0)} $$ converges then $g $ is an entire function.
Now, my doubt is if the above series is absolutely convergent then can we say something more about $g$, like say $g$ is a polynomial? I could not find any non-polynomial  entire function( I tried with functions like $e^z$, $\sin z $, et al), whose successive derivatives converge absolutely as series. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolog, we set $z_0=0$. Now we set
$$
g(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_nz^n}{n!}
$$
Then we find $g^{(n)}\left(z_0\right)=a_n.$ Choose any sequence $\left(a_n\right)$ with $\sum_n a_n<\infty$ and you get what you want.

Example:  $a_n = 2^{-n}$ results in $g(z) = e^{\frac{1}{2}z}$

Comment: Wow, that's a nice and a simple solution!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you gain much further information. If $g(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} c_n z^n$ then you ask for $\sum_{n\geq 0} n! |c_n| < +\infty$ which does not reduce to polynomials. Functions of this type (with fast convergence):
 $$ \sum_{n\geq 0} 2^{-n^2} z^n$$
or a more explicit example:
 $$ \cos(\sqrt{z}) = \sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{z^n}{(2n)!} $$
You might want to look at 'order' and 'type' in [Entire functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function)