# Prove that $f(z)$ is entire.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of  the origin and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f^{(n)}(0)$ converges. Prove that $f(z)$ extends to be an entire function.

From the given information I can guess that $f$ has a Taylor extension in the neighborhood of $0$, but how can we say that it is expandable to an entire function? Please tell me how can we prove that $f$ is entire. AS [Entire function and the series of its successive derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362670/entire-function-and-the-series-of-its-successive-derivatives) the answers to this question does not provide me satisfactory answer

Comment: The extension is $\sum_n \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n$ which converges for all $z$.